# How to calculate $\int_{b}^{c} (c-s)^{-3/4} (s-b)^{-3/4}ds$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to calculate the integral

$$ \int_b^c \! (c-s)^{-3/4} (s-b)^{-3/4}\,\mathrm{d}s $$

Thanks.

Comment: You can call $t-a$ as your new $a$ to reduce the number of symbols in your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have just changed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)?

Comment: After that, you might have a look at this page of [particular values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) of the Gamma function.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I understand. By substitution $t=\frac{s-b}{c-b}$ we obtain that the integral is equal $(c-b)^{-1/2} B(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$.

Comment: Yep. You could post this as an answer to your question (yes, this is allowed on the site, even recommended). // Thanks to you, I refreshed my memories about which values of Gamma are known... Not so many!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=\displaystyle\int_b^c (c-s)^{-3/4}(s-b)^{-3/4}ds$. By substitution $t=\dfrac{s-b}{c-b}$ we have $s-b=(c-b)t$, $c-s=(c-b)(1-t)$, $ds=(c-b)dt$. 
Hence
$$
I=\int_0^1 (c-b)^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-3/4}(c-b)^{-3/4}t^{-3/4}(c-b)dt=(c-b)^{-1/2}B\left(1/4,1/4\right),
$$ 
where $B$ is [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), defined as $B(u,v)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 (1-t)^{v-1}t^{u-1}dt$ for every positive $u$ and $v$.

Comment: +1. Cleaned up a little bit your LaTeX and added a link. If you mind, cancel these.

Comment: @Asaf, nightowl vandalized my editing and you did not clean up the mess. Consider that at present $I$ is not the integral the OP is interested in, that the arguments of Beta are wrong, and that the link to the WP page on the Beta function that I added is gone. Great. I suggest to come back to my version but I will not fight for this. In fact, at this point, I wish to (1) apologize to Richard and (2) disassociate myself from the editing process of this post.

Comment: @Didier: I am terribly sorry. It's hard to see through latex edits sometimes. Richard, I apologize for the mess I caused.

Comment: @Asaf: No problem.

Comment: @Richard, did I mention that if the answer suits you (wink, wink), you may accept it? (Good job, should you ask.)